# asciidoc: how to add callouts asciidoc to image

Tags: image, callout, asciidoc

How can i add callouts to images like in *docbook*? See an example here: http://norman.walsh.name/2006/06/10/imageobjectco

The callout points can be drawn on the image, but when i try to generate document from this:

```
image::img/stg.png[width=400,align="center"]
<1> Blabla.
<2> Foobar.
<3> Aknathnaratnathgarat.
```

... it drops an error:

```
asciidoc: WARNING: manual.adoc: line 580: no callouts refer to list item 1
asciidoc: WARNING: manual.adoc: line 581: no callouts refer to list item 2
asciidoc: WARNING: manual.adoc: line 582: no callouts refer to list item 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand that asciidoc uses docbook, looking for it in docbook I just found out how to do this:

```
++++
<mediaobjectco> 
  <imageobjectco>  
    <areaspec id="map1"  
              units="calspair">  
      <area linkends="callout1"  
            coords="1000,5000 6000,8000"  
            id="area1"/>  
    </areaspec>
    <imageobject>
      <imagedata fileref="images/notredame.png" />
    </imageobject>
    <calloutlist>
      <callout arearefs="area1" 
               id="callout1">  
        <para>My only callout</para>
      </callout>
    </calloutlist>
  </imageobjectco>
</mediaobjectco>
++++
```

You can copy and paste in asciidoc and it will work (the `++++` operator let you put docbook code inside asciidoc). Of course you will have to have the image at `images/notredame.png` to work, I have used [this image](http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/figures/notredame.png).

To understand more look for docbook documentation:

- http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Imagemaps.html (this example was extracted from there)
- http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/callout.html
- http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PrintIcons.html

NOTE: Asciidoc uses docbook 4.5, when looking at documentation skip 5.0 tags.

From time to time is need this feature in my books, but I end up puting a label in the image (like [mapa_a.png](https://github.com/edusantana/introducao-a-computacao-livro/blob/master/livro/images/tradutor/mapa_a.png) and this one [mapa_b.png](https://github.com/edusantana/introducao-a-computacao-livro/blob/master/livro/images/tradutor/mapa_b.png)), and put them side by side in a table with [inline image](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/chunked/ch21.html). You can see inline images [in this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edusantana/matematica-elementar-livro/master/livro/capitulos/cap4.adoc), find for `image:images/cap4`).

Comment: It's a _docbook_-only solution, but works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a real solution but partly acts like the original callouts:

```
:callouts: /usr/share/xml/docbook/stylesheet/docbook-xsl/images/callouts/

image::img/stg.png[width=400,align="center"]
image:{callouts}/1.svg[] Blabla.               +
image:{callouts}/2.svg[] Foobar.               +
image:{callouts}/3.svg[] Aknathnaratnathgarat.
```