# AsciiDoc: How can I place graphical hints on an image

Tags: pdf-generation, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am using AsciiDoc with [Asciidoctor Gradle Plugin](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin/) to generate technical documentation as PDF.

When I used M$ Word, I could easily place forms on an image, for example

1. colored rectangles,
2. boxes with numbers or
3. even links to sections within the document,

to better point out interesting areas within the image.

Example:

[image: Example image: A mockup with two rectangles and two links]

On the example image I have placed two rectangles and each one contains a link (starting with the word *«Dialogbereich»*) leading to a other sections within the document.

**Is it possible to achieve something like this (directly) in AsciiDoc?**

1. Note that the answers to [asciidoc: how to add callouts asciidoc to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734328/asciidoc-how-to-add-callouts-asciidoc-to-image) do not apply here as the Asciidoctor PDF backend does not use DocBook to generate the PDF.
2. I know I could create a layered image in GIMP to at least place the rectangles. However, that wouldn't help me with the links.